# Deploying Shopify App In Netlify But Not Working

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, shopify-app

I have developed the Shopify app using the [Shopify PHP app template](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php),
after completing development, I tried to deploy the app on Netlify.com,
and deployment is done successfully.

From Netlify, Netlify accesses the App via the GitHub repository.

I have an Import App repository in Netlify:

**Here in the last image, What should I need to add in Publish Directory field?**

**like my app was run the component,**

**directory is : /Shopify-app/web/frontend/components/ProductsCard.jsx**

**ProductsCard.jsx is main file that produced the Shopify App Output,
when run the "npm run dev" command.**

[image: Success Deployment on Netlify]

but when I run the Netlify domain it gives an error:

[image: Page Not Found Error]

also, I have added the Environment Variable in Netlify:

[image: Environment Variable in Netlify]

In my local system, I run the app using the `npm run dev` command. It creates the Cloudflare tunnel, and I copy that tunnel and paste it to the browser and my app was run, but how to set up this kind of URL in Netlify?

Example:

> https://reveals-cooperation-diamond.trycloudflare.com?shop=mysite.myshopify.com&host=bmNvZGVzaG9wLm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4

Please let me know what mistakes I do here so that my App was not run.

Comment: What should I need to add in Publish Directory, field from the last image?